# How do I fix the "ConnectionError: failed to connect to <server>:<port> in 15000ms" error?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

First time creating a Node/Express api to an Azure SQL Server database. It seems like this is just a matter of extending the timeout limit, but it's also just a connection to the database and not an actual query. Is this normal for connecting to Azure and is it actually an issue that extending the timeout will fix or is something else the problem?

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const sql = require("../dboperation")

/* GET root route */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

// Test db connection
router.get('/testconnect', function(req, res, next) {
  sql.getdata();
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**dboperation.js**

```
var config = require("./dbconfig")
const sql = require("mssql")


async function getdata(){
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        console.log("SQL Server connnected...")
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getdata: getdata,
}
```

**dbconfig.js**

```
const config = {
    user : "username",
    password : "password",
    server : "server-name.database.windows.net",
    database : "database-name",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true, 
        enableArithAort: true,
        encrypt: true
    },
    port: 49678
}

module.exports = config;
```

SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I *assume* that the firewall in Azure allows your IP to connect to the remote instance?

Comment: "how do I fix it", well it depends what the problem is. This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: @Larnu - yes, Azure firewall is setup up to allow my IP. I can actually run queries in SSMS to the Azure db successfully.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed, you provide a username and password *and* specify `trustedConnection: true`; that doesn't make sense. You either provide the Username and Password *or* use a trusted connection.

Comment: I removed ```trustedConnection: true``` but still get the error.

Comment: There's only three likely problems for that specific error message: 1. the server name is incorrect (or resolves to an incorrect IP address), 2. the port is incorrect, or 3. there's a firewall somewhere between the Node server and the SQL Server instance. For example, if it were connecting successfully but not trusting the self-signed SSL certificate it would report `Failed to connect to fully.qualified.server.name:portNumber - unable to verify the first certificate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by extending timeout once.

Assuming you have set the appropriate environment variables, you can construct a config object as follows:

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const sqlConfig = {

  user: process.env.DB_USER,

  password: process.env.DB_PWD,

  database: process.env.DB_NAME,

  server: 'localhost',

  pool: {

    max: 10,

    min: 0,

    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000

  },

  options: {

    encrypt: true, // for azure

    trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs

  }

}



async () => {

 try {

  // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string

  await sql.connect(sqlConfig)

  const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`

  console.dir(result)

 } catch (err) {

  // ... error checks

 }

}
```

Reference link - https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/